# What are the requirements to retain custom document properties when exporting to PDF

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, metadata

SharePoint colums (metadata) add extra document properties to the Word document.
When I download such a document I can view the extra properties In Word with File>Info>Show All Properties.
When I export the file to PDF with File>Export>Create PDF/XPS, with document properties checked in Options, the extra document properties are not transferred or not visiable in the resulting PDF document.
What are the requirements to retain the custom properties in PDF and show them?
Do I need specific software or specific version, I use the latest version of Office 365 and SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint online supports mapping the columns in the Document library to the **Office(Word, Excel, PPT...) Document Properties Panel**, but does not support mapping to the PDF files, even if the PDF file is converted/exported by the Office files.

[image]

Comment: It is not about SharePoint Online mapping to PDF files.

Comment: It is not about SharePoint Online mapping to PDF files.It is about the extra document properties which are added to the Word document by SharePoint.
According to Adobe, Word custom properties can be exported to PDF as metadata.
Are these properties added by SharePoint no custom properties but something else?
Question is how to export documents in SharePoint to PDF archive documents with the metadata necessary from the Library metadata?

Comment: Based on my research, we could not export the metadata columns in the Documents libraries to the PDF files, it is by design. I would suggest you submit a feedback via User Voice. [ https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/ ]

Comment: I have post the same question in the following forums:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292494/what-are-the-requirements-to-retain-custom-document-properties-when-exporting-to
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/346553/how-do-i-save-a-word-document-as-a-pdf-such-that-c.html
https://eileenslounge.com/
https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/how-to-convert-word-to-pdf-with-sharepoint-metadata/m-p/11959431#M307413
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_custom-mso_365hp/how-to-retain-extra-sharepoint-document-properties/

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiastic sharing.

Comment: See Greg Maxey's code to create regular custom document properties from the SharePoint properties, which then are incorporated into the pdf.   https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-retain-extra-sharepoint-document-properties/3f6e9194-0b63-4177-8a96-25f2f20317a5?LastReply=true#LastReply